# Correct android progressbar spinner implementation

Tags: android, progress-bar

Following is the snip of relevant portion of resource file (activity_main.xml):

```
 <Button android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_get"
    android:onClick="getData" />

<ProgressBar
  android:id="@+id/pbar"
  style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:indeterminate="true" />
```

The following is snip from MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ...

private ProgressBar spinner;

    ...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

...

spinner = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbar);
spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    ...
}

protected void getData(View view) {

    ...

    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // Do some task here

    spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    ...

}
```

The progress bar is not shown after clicking the button. However, as per some documentation that I read through, it is necessary to start the progress bar in a thread instead of the above way. How should a threaded implementation for progress bar be done for the above design

Comment: getData must be called from a baxkground thread, if you do some long operations in the UI thread you will get ANR error

Comment: But getData is called by android:onClick="getData" in the Button

Comment: so you need to di it in a separate thread

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the progress bar directly in widget you can try the following..

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case 0:
        ProgressDialog ProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        ProgressDialog
                .setMessage("Please wait...");
        ProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        ProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        ProgressDialog.show();
        ProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        ProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        return ProgressDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
 /**
 * Background Async Task 
 * */
class IsContinue extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Bar Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(0);

    }

    /**
     * Background task
     */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
// Do something here
 }
 /**
     * After executing background task
     */
    protected void onPostExecute(String Value) {
 dismissDialog(0);
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. However there is a warning saying that "The method showDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated"

Comment: That is not a problem, showDialog(int) is the one which is used in previous android APIs. For now it has changed which i haven't tried. Accept the answer if you are ok with this..